# How to access objects in S3 bucket, without making the object's folder public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have provided AmazonS3FullAccess policy for both the IAM user and group. Also the buket that I am trying to access says "Objects can be public". I have explicitly made the folder inside the bucket public. Despite all this I am getting access denied error when I tried to access it through its url. Any idea on this?

Comment: " explicitly made the folder inside the bucket public" - made how? Any bucket policy, ACL? How do you access the objects exactly?

Comment: you can keep your bucket private and all folders private, you can access with signed url https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html

Comment: How are you accessing the content? For example, via the management console? AWS CLI? Web browser? If using a web browser, how are you identifying yourself to S3?

Comment: Accessing via web browser. I generated a key and secret pair for that user for authentication and then by creating pre-signed url.

Comment: @Marcin Click on that bucket to open - Under action column click "Make Public". Then I tried giving a policy as well. Still the object was private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects in Amazon S3 are private by default. This means that objects are not accessible by anonymous users.

You have granted permission for your IAM User to be able to access S3. Therefore, you have access to the objects **but you must identify yourself to S3** so that it can verify your identity.

You should be able to access S3 content:

- Via the Amazon S3 management console
- Using the AWS CLI (eg `aws s3 ls s3://bucketname`)
- Via authenticated requests in a web browser

I suspect that you have been accessing your bucket via an **unauthenticated request** (eg `bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/foo.txt`. Unfortunately, this does not tell Amazon S3 who you are, so it will deny the request.

To access content with this type of URL, you can generate an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which appends some authentication information to the URL to prove your identity. An easy way to generate the URL is with the AWS CLI:

```
aws s3 presign s3://bucketname/foo.txt
```

It will return a URL that looks like this:

```
https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/foo.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAxxx&Signature=xxx&Expires=1608175109
```

The URL will be valid for one hour by default, up to 7 days.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways I will recommend.

1. go to **s3 dashboard**, and download the object you need, one by one manually, the bucket can be kept private at the same time.
2. **build a gateway/a small service**, to handle authentication for you, set a policy and give the permission to the service container/lambda to visit the private bucket, and restrict only specific users to download the objects.

### References

- [download from aws s3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/download-objects.html)
- [aws policy, permission and roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction_access-management.html)